# Jquery Validation in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am not trying to get to fancy with my client side validation this go round.  Maybe for a future project, but I just want some basic form validation for my forms...

I know you can link the stuff to your model or whatever, but I really just want to display an error message to the client if his entry isn't correct.  However, I am having a hard time getting any validation at all to work.  So I am guess I am missing something rather simple.  I thought I had all my bases covered, but apparently not.

Here are the scripts that I included into my project and onto the view...

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I don't think there is an error because the masked input is working...  But I really should open up my debugger to make sure.  I will as soon as I am done with this post.

Here is where I am doing some general validation...

```
$("eEncId").validate({
            rules: {DateOfBirth: {
                    required: true
                }
}
})
```

The form seems to submit whether or not I have a DateOfBirth...
What am I missing?

**UPDATE: Posting html output...**

```
<form action="/EditEncounter/Save?popid=2" id="eEncId" method="post"><label for="Active">Deactivate</label><input id="Active" name="Active" type="radio" value="N" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EncounterId must be a number." data-val-required="The EncounterId field is required." id="EncounterId" name="EncounterId" type="hidden" value="1898" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EMPIID must be a number." data-val-required="The EMPIID field is required." id="EMPIID" name="EMPIID" type="hidden" value="0" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PatientId must be a number." data-val-required="The PatientId field is required." id="PatientId" name="PatientId" type="hidden" value="4433" />    <table width="500" class="odd">
        <tr><td>
            <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label> 
            </td>
            <td><input Value="RAYFIELD" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="RAYFIELD" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="BOYD" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="BOYD" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="DateOfBirth">DateOfBirth</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="03/06/1947 00:00:00" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DateOfBirth must be a date." id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="text" value="3/6/1947 12:00:00 AM" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="4124880798" id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="4124880798" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="HostpitalFinNumber">HostpitalFinNumber</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="6669511596226" id="HostpitalFinNumber" name="HostpitalFinNumber" type="text" value="6669511596226" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="AdminDate">AdminDate</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="03/02/2012 00:00:00" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field AdminDate must be a date." id="AdminDate" name="AdminDate" type="text" value="3/2/2012 12:00:00 AM" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="MRNType">MRNType</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="MPACMRN" id="MRNType" name="MRNType" type="text" value="MPACMRN" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="MRN">MRN</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="785528039" id="MRN" name="MRN" type="text" value="785528039" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="PatientRoomPhone">PatientRoomPhone</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="" id="PatientRoomPhone" name="PatientRoomPhone" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="DischargeDateTime">DischargeDateTime</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DischargeDateTime must be a date." id="DischargeDateTime" name="DischargeDateTime" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="DischargeDisposition">DischargeDisposition</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="" id="DischargeDisposition" name="DischargeDisposition" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="DischargeTo">DischargeTo</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="" id="DischargeTo" name="DischargeTo" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="DischargeAdvocateCall">DischargeAdvocateCall</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="" id="DischargeAdvocateCall" name="DischargeAdvocateCall" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="Payor">Payor</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="" id="Payor" name="Payor" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="HomeHealthCareAccepted">HomeHealthCareAccepted</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input Value="" id="HomeHealthCareAccepted" name="HomeHealthCareAccepted" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="SafeLandingAccepted">SafeLandingAccepted</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="" id="SafeLandingAccepted" name="SafeLandingAccepted" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="PCPName">PCPName</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="Dr. Peggy Halsey" id="PCPName" name="PCPName" type="text" value="Dr. Peggy Halsey" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="PCPPhone">PCPPhone</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="4126244141" id="PCPPhone" name="PCPPhone" type="text" value="4126244141" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>    
            <label for="SpecialistName">SpecialistName</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="" id="SpecialistName" name="SpecialistName" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="SpecialistPhone">SpecialistPhone</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="" id="SpecialistPhone" name="SpecialistPhone" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="PCPAppointmentDateTime">PCPAppointmentDateTime</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field PCPAppointmentDateTime must be a date." id="PCPAppointmentDateTime" name="PCPAppointmentDateTime" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="PCPAppointmentLocation">PCPAppointmentLocation</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="" id="PCPAppointmentLocation" name="PCPAppointmentLocation" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="SpecialistAppointmentDateTime">SpecialistAppointmentDateTime</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field SpecialistAppointmentDateTime must be a date." id="SpecialistAppointmentDateTime" name="SpecialistAppointmentDateTime" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="SpecialistAppointmentLocation">SpecialistAppointmentLocation</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="" id="SpecialistAppointmentLocation" name="SpecialistAppointmentLocation" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="CompletedPathway">CompletedPathway</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="1" id="CompletedPathway" name="CompletedPathway" type="text" value="1" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="CompletedPathwayReason">CompletedPathwayReason</label>
            </td><td>
            <input Value="" id="CompletedPathwayReason" name="CompletedPathwayReason" type="text" value="" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <label for="Comment">Comment</label>
            </td><td>
            <textarea Value="" cols="20" id="Comment" name="Comment" rows="2">
</textarea>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" id="btClick"/>
    </p> 
</form>
```

I checked the Id's of the appropriate fields, and everything seems to check out.  Very mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missing the # from the ID in your code block try this:

```
$("#eEncId").validate({
            rules: {DateOfBirth: {
                    required: true
                }
    }
});
```

Comment: hmmm.  Good eye.  I don't know why always keep forgetting that.  But It still doesn't work somehow.  I looked through the debugger and it doesn't appear as though I have a javascript exception.  Hmmm.  Mysterious.

Comment: Could you post your output html - might just be a formatting issue?!

Answer (score 0):

Whoops!
I accidentally had the validate script in my layout file as well as my View.cshtml file.
This probably caused some conflicts.  The validation now seems to be taking root.